# Laravel Input replace is not working when input is inside the constructor

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

I have the following constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $relations = \Input::get('relations');
}
```

I'm trying to replace an Input in unit test, but since input is inside the constructor, I can't replace it. If I put Input::get('relations') outside of the constructor it works.

what I tried is:

```
\Input::replace(array('relations'=>'relName'));
\Request::replace(array('relations'=>'relName'));
```

Both of them work outside of the constructor and none of them work inside the constructor.

Any body can help me?

Comment: Where is that constructor placed? Tell more info.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to mock a Facade here. You should check the latest docs on how you should be mocking Facades in tests:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing

The idea is that basically you can use Mockery's methods like `shouldReceive` etc

For example:

```
<?php

class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testGetIndex()
    {
        Cache::shouldReceive('get')
                    ->once()
                    ->with('key')
                    ->andReturn('value');

        $this->visit('/users')->see('value');
    }
}
```

This way you will not need `Input::replace` at all.